# asp.net sitemap breadcrumbs in microservice web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitemap, microservices, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a asp.net web application that will be undergoing some technology upgrades. First, the application will be upgraded from asp.net Web Forms to asp.net MVC. Second,  the application will be broken apart from a monolith into microservices.

My question is this: If the application ends up with microservices A, B, & C, and I have a page in the application that will have a breadcrumb trail of {Page in A} > {Page in B} > {Page in C}, how do I configure the sitemap to do this?

Comment: If you create microservices then you will have multiple completely separated applications. It will be like you have different websites.

Comment: I agree. Are there typical approaches or specific technologies to handle such circumstances?

Comment: What "circumstances"? Splitting a monolith to microservices?

Comment: I'm asking about the sitemap configuration. Making the sitemap such that it will work with all parts of the application - each of which will have a different URL.

Comment: You will have 3 different applications.

Comment: Not 3 parts of thecsame web application. But 3 different, stand alone web applications. You will probably have 3 sitemaps.

Comment: Ok. Lets say my application has 3 microservices (A, B, & C), and the application has a page were the breadcrumb trail should show: {Page from A} > {Page from B} > {Page from C}. Will having 3 separate sitemaps - one for each microservice - be able to produce such a breadcrumb trail? If so, any guidance on achieving that would be appreciated.

Comment: Breadcrumb generation is an `asp` specific thing, I can't. But when moving to microservices one must realize that they are separate application, with separate databases and possibly separated programming languages.